# Protected ISO File

Tags: usb, files, iso

I face a strange problem. Few days before I have downloaded matlab 2014a and it was downloaded in the form of ISO image file. But when I try to copy the ISO image file to my pen drive from the system it says "not enough space" even I was using 16GB empty pen drive. I want to know how to copy that ISO file in my pen drive.File size is 8GB.Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: What's the filesystem of your pen drive?

Comment: The filesystem is likely to be fat32 for a pen drive. The FAT32 filesystem does not support files larger than 4 GB, so your ISO image does not fit. What does ls -l /path/to/matlab2014a.iso (or whatever the iso is called) give you? Add it to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.Its very simple.Normally when we format the pen drive then file system we choose is FAT32. but this time we have to choose the file system NTFS. and then format it. By this I have transferred the ISO file of 4 GB in 8 GB pen drive. Problem occured because FAT32 file system does not allow to transfer the file more than FAT32.